# Celery dependency to tasks location

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I have several registered tasks in my app and it's working as expected but i moved my async tasks to another path recently and i realized that my old tasks those were registered by old app where calling the old same path and raising errors because the task were not there any more. now i'm looking for a solution to register tasks independently to location or find a way to update the tasks path.

Comment: You can import the task and [call it directly](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a patch. I left the tasks in the old location and made a copy of them in the new location and imported tasks from new location under the old tasks. this way celery creates new tasks from new location also celery can find tasks in their old location and empty its old tasks. old tasks can be removed after all old tasks are done.